# What is the limit of function $P_k(t) = (1-t)^k/C_k^n$, $t\in (0, 1)$ in sup norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the limit of function $P_k(t) = (1-t)^k/C_k^n$, $t\in (0, 1)$ in sup norm as $k \to \infty$? Here, $n \in \Bbb N$ is fixed and $C_k^n = \binom k n$ for $k \ge n$.

Comment: $C_k^n$ is what?

Comment: @s.harp:  My guess is binomial coefficient $C_k^n = \binom{n}{k}$.  But the OP wrote that "$n$ is any integer less than or equal to $k$", which makes that interpretation pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is zero. $T$ is between $0$ and $1$ and therefore the limit is zero.